# Trying to create a deployment file for AWS lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a Alexa skill that tells me when the next train time is at my train station. I want to use a package called pygtfs which is a library that models information stored in Google's General Transit Feed Specification (GTFS) format. I have the files that process the json object sent from alexa and they work fine. I am having trouble making a zip deployment package to upload to aws lambda. I have a python script that creates a deployment package but I am getting an error. The error does not add the correct files to the deployment package.

```
def _copy_deployment_files(deployment_dir):
    for deployment_file in deployment_files:
        if os.path.exists(deployment_file):
            cmd = "cp{0}{1}".format(deployment_file, deployment_dir).split()
        --->return_code = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=False)<----
        else:
            raise NameError("Deployment file not found [{0}]".format(deployment_file))
```

In the _copy_deployment_files function have tried making the subprocess method shell parameter to true

```
return_code = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

but it doesn't include the AlexaBaseHandler.py, AlexaDeploymentHandler.py and main.py.

**My questions is how do I get the create_development to add AlexaBaseHandler.py, AlexaDeploymentHandler.py and main.py to the deployment package and how to I ensure the pygtfs package is installed into the deployment package as well?**

Here is the result when return_code = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)

```
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/Owner/PycharmProjects/PatcoSchedule/create_deployment.py
Collecting requests==2.8.1
  Using cached requests-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: requests
Successfully installed requests-2.8.1
Collecting sseclient==0.0.11
Collecting requests>=2.0.0 (from sseclient==0.0.11)
  Using cached requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six (from sseclient==0.0.11)
  Using cached six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests>=2.0.0->sseclient==0.0.11)
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 (from requests>=2.0.0->sseclient==0.0.11)
  Using cached urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests>=2.0.0->sseclient==0.0.11)
  Using cached certifi-2017.7.27.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<2.7,>=2.5 (from requests>=2.0.0->sseclient==0.0.11)
  Using cached idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: chardet, urllib3, certifi, idna, requests, six, sseclient
Successfully installed certifi-2017.7.27.1 chardet-3.0.4 idna-2.6 requests-2.18.4 six-1.11.0 sseclient-0.0.11 urllib3-1.22
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\requests already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Collecting hammock==0.2.4
Collecting requests>=1.1.0 (from hammock==0.2.4)
  Using cached requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<2.7,>=2.5 (from requests>=1.1.0->hammock==0.2.4)
  Using cached idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 (from requests>=1.1.0->hammock==0.2.4)
  Using cached urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests>=1.1.0->hammock==0.2.4)
  Using cached certifi-2017.7.27.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests>=1.1.0->hammock==0.2.4)
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: idna, urllib3, certifi, chardet, requests, hammock
Successfully installed certifi-2017.7.27.1 chardet-3.0.4 hammock-0.2.4 idna-2.6 requests-2.18.4 urllib3-1.22
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\certifi already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\certifi-2017.7.27.1.dist-info already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\chardet already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\chardet-3.0.4.dist-info already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\idna already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\idna-2.6.dist-info already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\requests already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\requests-2.18.4.dist-info already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\urllib3 already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\urllib3-1.22.dist-info already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\__pycache__ already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Collecting pygtfs==0.1.3
  Using cached pygtfs-0.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting sqlalchemy>=0.7.8 (from pygtfs==0.1.3)
  Using cached SQLAlchemy-1.1.14.tar.gz
Collecting six (from pygtfs==0.1.3)
  Using cached six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz>=2012d (from pygtfs==0.1.3)
  Using cached pytz-2017.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting docopt (from pygtfs==0.1.3)
Installing collected packages: sqlalchemy, six, pytz, docopt, pygtfs
  Running setup.py install for sqlalchemy: started
    Running setup.py install for sqlalchemy: finished with status 'done'
Successfully installed docopt-0.6.2 pygtfs-0.1.3 pytz-2017.2 six-1.11.0 sqlalchemy-1.1.14
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\six-1.11.0.dist-info already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\six.py already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\__pycache__ already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.

Process finished with exit code 0
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/Owner/PycharmProjects/PatcoSchedule/create_deployment.py
Collecting requests==2.8.1
  Using cached requests-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: requests
Successfully installed requests-2.8.1
Collecting sseclient==0.0.11
Collecting requests>=2.0.0 (from sseclient==0.0.11)
  Using cached requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six (from sseclient==0.0.11)
  Using cached six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests>=2.0.0->sseclient==0.0.11)
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 (from requests>=2.0.0->sseclient==0.0.11)
  Using cached urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests>=2.0.0->sseclient==0.0.11)
  Using cached certifi-2017.7.27.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<2.7,>=2.5 (from requests>=2.0.0->sseclient==0.0.11)
  Using cached idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: chardet, urllib3, certifi, idna, requests, six, sseclient
Successfully installed certifi-2017.7.27.1 chardet-3.0.4 idna-2.6 requests-2.18.4 six-1.11.0 sseclient-0.0.11 urllib3-1.22
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\requests already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Collecting hammock==0.2.4
Collecting requests>=1.1.0 (from hammock==0.2.4)
  Using cached requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<2.7,>=2.5 (from requests>=1.1.0->hammock==0.2.4)
  Using cached idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 (from requests>=1.1.0->hammock==0.2.4)
  Using cached urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests>=1.1.0->hammock==0.2.4)
  Using cached certifi-2017.7.27.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests>=1.1.0->hammock==0.2.4)
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: idna, urllib3, certifi, chardet, requests, hammock
Successfully installed certifi-2017.7.27.1 chardet-3.0.4 hammock-0.2.4 idna-2.6 requests-2.18.4 urllib3-1.22
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\certifi already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\certifi-2017.7.27.1.dist-info already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\chardet already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\chardet-3.0.4.dist-info already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\idna already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\idna-2.6.dist-info already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\requests already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\requests-2.18.4.dist-info already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\urllib3 already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\urllib3-1.22.dist-info already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\__pycache__ already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Collecting pygtfs==0.1.3
  Using cached pygtfs-0.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting sqlalchemy>=0.7.8 (from pygtfs==0.1.3)
  Using cached SQLAlchemy-1.1.14.tar.gz
Collecting six (from pygtfs==0.1.3)
  Using cached six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz>=2012d (from pygtfs==0.1.3)
  Using cached pytz-2017.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting docopt (from pygtfs==0.1.3)
Installing collected packages: sqlalchemy, six, pytz, docopt, pygtfs
  Running setup.py install for sqlalchemy: started
    Running setup.py install for sqlalchemy: finished with status 'done'
Successfully installed docopt-0.6.2 pygtfs-0.1.3 pytz-2017.2 six-1.11.0 sqlalchemy-1.1.14
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\six-1.11.0.dist-info already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\six.py already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\PatcoSchedule\deployments\deployment_15\__pycache__ already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Here is the create_deployment file and the code was copied from https://github.com/youngsoul/AlexaDeploymentSample

```
import os
import subprocess
import zipfile


"""
Script will create an AWS Lambda function deployment.

It expects there to be a deployments directory and it will create a
deployment of the form:

deployment_n

where n is incremented for each deployment based on the existing deployment
directories

"""

root_deployments_dir = "./deployments"

# List of files that should be included in the deployment
# Only the files listed here, and the libraries in the requirements.txt
# file will be included in the deployment.
deployment_files = ['AlexaBaseHandler.py', 'AlexaDeploymentHandler.py', 'main.py']

def _read_requirements():
    with open("./requirements.txt", 'r') as f:
        install_requirements = f.readlines()

    return install_requirements

def _get_immediate_subdirectories(a_dir):
    return [name for name in os.listdir(a_dir)
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(a_dir, name))]

def _make_deployment_dir():
    all_deployment_directories = _get_immediate_subdirectories(root_deployments_dir)
    max_deployment_number = -1
    for deployment_dir in all_deployment_directories:
        dir_name_elements = deployment_dir.split("_")
        if( len(dir_name_elements) == 2):
            if int(dir_name_elements[1]) > max_deployment_number:
                max_deployment_number = int(dir_name_elements[1])

    if max_deployment_number == -1:
        max_deployment_number = 0

    deployment_name = "deployment_{0}".format(max_deployment_number+1)
    new_deployment_dir_path = "{0}/{1}".format(root_deployments_dir, deployment_name)

    if not os.path.exists(new_deployment_dir_path):
        os.mkdir(new_deployment_dir_path)

    return (new_deployment_dir_path, deployment_name)

def _install_requirements(deployment_requirements, deployment_dir):
    """
    pip install <requirements line> -t <deployment_dir>
    :param deployment_requirements
    :param deployment_dir:
    :return:
    """
    if os.path.exists(deployment_dir):
        for requirement in deployment_requirements:
            cmd = "pip install {0} -t {1}".format(requirement, deployment_dir).split()
            return_code = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=False)

def _copy_deployment_files(deployment_dir):
    for deployment_file in deployment_files:
        if os.path.exists(deployment_file):
            cmd = "{0} {1}".format(deployment_file, deployment_dir).split()
            return_code = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=False)
        else:
            raise NameError("Deployment file not found [{0}]".format(deployment_file))


def zipdir(dirPath=None, zipFilePath=None, includeDirInZip=False):
    """
    Attribution:  I wish I could remember where I found this on the
    web.  To the unknown sharer of knowledge - thank you.

    Create a zip archive from a directory.

    Note that this function is designed to put files in the zip archive with
    either no parent directory or just one parent directory, so it will trim any
    leading directories in the filesystem paths and not include them inside the
    zip archive paths. This is generally the case when you want to just take a
    directory and make it into a zip file that can be extracted in different
    locations.

    Keyword arguments:

    dirPath -- string path to the directory to archive. This is the only
    required argument. It can be absolute or relative, but only one or zero
    leading directories will be included in the zip archive.

    zipFilePath -- string path to the output zip file. This can be an absolute
    or relative path. If the zip file already exists, it will be updated. If
    not, it will be created. If you want to replace it from scratch, delete it
    prior to calling this function. (default is computed as dirPath + ".zip")

    includeDirInZip -- boolean indicating whether the top level directory should
    be included in the archive or omitted. (default True)

"""
    if not zipFilePath:
        zipFilePath = dirPath + ".zip"
    if not os.path.isdir(dirPath):
        raise OSError("dirPath argument must point to a directory. "
            "'%s' does not." % dirPath)
    parentDir, dirToZip = os.path.split(dirPath)
    #Little nested function to prepare the proper archive path
    def trimPath(path):
        archivePath = path.replace(parentDir, "", 1)
        if parentDir:
            archivePath = archivePath.replace(os.path.sep, "", 1)
        if not includeDirInZip:
            archivePath = archivePath.replace(dirToZip + os.path.sep, "", 1)
        return os.path.normcase(archivePath)

    outFile = zipfile.ZipFile(zipFilePath, "w",
        compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for (archiveDirPath, dirNames, fileNames) in os.walk(dirPath):
        for fileName in fileNames:
            filePath = os.path.join(archiveDirPath, fileName)
            outFile.write(filePath, trimPath(filePath))
        #Make sure we get empty directories as well
        if not fileNames and not dirNames:
            #or
            #zipInfo.external_attr = 48
            #Here to allow for inserting an empty directory.  Still TBD/TODO.
            outFile.writestr(zipInfo, "")
    outFile.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    (deployment_dir, deployment_name) = _make_deployment_dir()
    _copy_deployment_files(deployment_dir)
    install_requirements = _read_requirements()
    _install_requirements(install_requirements, deployment_dir)

    zipdir(deployment_dir, "{0}/{1}.zip".format(root_deployments_dir, deployment_name))
```

**UPDATE**

NVM i figured it out. The code I copied was using cp as the copy command for the subprocess. I looked up the command for my OS (windows 10) and it was COPY not cp. here is the new call to subprocess

```
cmd = "COPY {0}
    {1}".format(deployment_file,os.path.abspath(deployment_dir)).split()
```

Comment: NVM i figured it out. The code I copied was using cp as the copy command for the subprocess. I looked up the command for my OS (windows 10) and it was COPY not cp. here is the new call to subprocess             cmd = "COPY {0} {1}".format(deployment_file, os.path.abspath(deployment_dir)).split()

Comment: You should add that as an answer, and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM i figured it out. The code I copied was using cp as the copy command for the subprocess. I looked up the command for my OS (windows 10) and it was COPY not cp. here is the new call to subprocess cmd = "COPY {0} {1}".format(deployment_file, os.path.abspath(deployment_dir)).split()